# Convert Column with existing data to another type in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to convert a 'shippingDays' column in postgres with existing data that is type varchar to an integer.

Current Data:

1. '0-7 Days' should be converted to 7
2. '8-14 Days' should be converted to 14
3. '15-30 Days' should be converted to 30
4. 'Over 30 Days' should be converted to 31

What's the best way to go about with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_column = CASE WHEN your_column='Over 30 Days' THEN '31' ELSE regexp_replace(your_column, '\d+-(\d+) Days', E'\\1', 'g') END
```

Test with:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN your_column='Over 30 Days' THEN '31' ELSE regexp_replace(your_column, '\d+-(\d+) Days', E'\\1', 'g') END
FROM your_table
```

For new column:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_new_column = CASE WHEN your_column='Over 30 Days' THEN 31 ELSE CAST(regexp_replace(your_column, '\d+-(\d+) Days', E'\\1', 'g') AS INTEGER) END
```

Comment: and if I want to do a rollback? how would you go about with it?

Comment: First, test it with the Statement under "Test with:" otherwiese:
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE your_table
SET your_column = regexp_replace(your_column, '\d+-(\d+) Days', E'\\1', 'g');
SELECT *
FROM your_table;
ROLLBACK;

Comment: also, curious if these changes the column's data type automatically too? if I add new data.

Comment: The best way is you add a new column with the new datatype and than store the value in that column.

Comment: is it possible to reuse that column tho? so, copy existing data, change column data type, then add existing data to the same column with new data type and convert it so it's compatible.